# Were any Imperial Officers opposed to the Death Star?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

In Marvel's *Darth Vader* comic, we run into an officer who talks to Vader about the Death Star.  He calls it Tarkin's folly, and wonders how many super star destroyers could have been built using the same resources.

Was this a very small minority? Were there any other officers opposed to the Death Star(s)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Yes

Various loyal Imperials were opposed to the Death Star. For example, Jylia Shale, one of the Empire’s top strategists:

> “The strategy of the Galactic Empire,” Shale begins, “was not under my
> supreme control. I’ll make it clear yet again that I disagreed with
> both implementations of the Death Star. I opposed its creation from
> the very beginning—and in fact, that opposition marginalized my input
> going forward."
>
> <sub>*Star Wars: Aftermath*</sub>

As well as Grand Moff Pandion:

> Moff Pandion—Grand Moff Pandion, apparently—stands up, begins to pace
> a semicircle around his end of the table. “I for once agree with Jylia
> Shale. Not just that the Death Star was our greatest mistake, but also
> that no truce will suffice.
>
> <sub>*Star Wars: Aftermath*</sub>

Shale’s statement suggests that Tarkin (and Palpatine) intentionally ignored the advice of those who opposed the Death Star’s creation. They were both heavily invested in its development, whether as a symbol of the power of the Empire (Tarkin) or that of the Dark Side (Palpatine).

One thing to keep in mind is that opposition to the Death Star could not have been widespread around the time of its construction, simply because *knowledge of its existence* was not widespread. But the presence of doubts among several of the Empire’s top command suggests that opposition may have been fairly common among those who knew about it.

Comment: The point raised in your last paragraph had also popped into my mind as soon as I saw the question. In the original movie, it was clear that the Death Star was coming as a huge surprise to most people (though the Rebels had gotten wind of it). For instance, Han Solo must have *never even heard* of any serious plans for construction of a space station anywhere near that size -- since he initially rejected Obi-Wan's statement that it *was* a space station, rather than a small moon. If Han had known the Empire was supposed to be building such a thing, he wouldn't have been nearly so skeptical.